# Linux Ubuntu: Updating the GRUB menu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub

So apparently there are 2 versions of Linux on my laptop(I have a dual boot system with Linux and Windows 8 but Linux is the master OS). One of them uses the Kernel version 3.11.0 whose headers + source code are incompatible with my wireless driver. My laptop is a Toshiba Satellite with a Realtek RTL8188CE wireless lan.So the newer kernel version is still the first option on the menu and to get to Linux I use the "Previous versions of linux" which is running Kernel version 3.2.0-55 and the wifi driver works just fine with that verions(thank Gawd!).

What can I do to update the grub menu so that Linux version with the 3.2.0-55 Kernel appears as the primary option? Do I need to get rid of/uninstall the newer kernel version? How can I do this without screwing up Linux entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could uninstall the newer kernel and the GRUB menu will be updated automatically, as long as you make sure not to install any updated kernel packages.

A better solution is to edit the GRUB menu directly. You can either use the `grub-set-default` command (as root), or edit the file manually.

In the latter case, the file you need to edit is `/etc/default/grub`. Change the `GRUB_DEFAULT` entry to either the numeric position (0, 1, 2...) or the exact name (e. g. `Ubuntu, Linux 3.2.0-55-generic`) of the menu item you want to boot.

Or, use `sudo grub-set-default <foo>` where `<foo>` is either the position or name as above.

[More information](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#Configuring_GRUB_2) on configuring GRUB.

Comment: Can I do this from a GNOME terminal? Or do I need to restart and go directly into the GRUB shell?

Comment: Yes, you would do this from a GNOME terminal (or any other terminal), not the GRUB shell.